# How to Exit and Kill the Running Docker Container with CTRL+C?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

TL; DR: how should I write a `Dockerfile` or docker commands to run docker containers so that I can stop and exit the running docker container when I hit `ctrl+c`?

---

#### Background

I need to run an infinite while loop in shell script. When I ran this script locally, the `ctrl+c` command will exit the infinite loop.

```
# content of sync.sh

while true; do
  echo "Do something!"
  some_syncing_command || {
    rm -rf /tmp/healthy && break
  }
  echo "Finish doing something!"
  touch /tmp/healthy
  sleep ${waitingSeconds}
done
```

So based on the shell script, I then created a Docker Image with the following `Dockerfile` content:

```
FROM debian:stretch 
COPY sync.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["/sync.sh"]
```

and build the image by running `docker build -t infinite-loop .`

#### Problem

However, after trying different attempts to run the `infinite-loop` image, I cannot stop and exit the running docker container after hitting `ctrl + c`. Here are the docker commands I used to run the docker image:

1. `docker run --rm to-infinity-1 infinite-loop`
2. `docker run --rm -it to-infinity-2 infinite-loop`
3. `docker run --rm -d to-infinity-3 infinite-loop`, then run `docker attach` on `to-infinity-3`

All of the above commands fail to stop and exit the infinite loop after executing `ctrl+c` directly. Hence I need to run `docker stop [container-name]` to stop the running containers of infinite loops. What should I change in my implementation to resolve this problem?

Thank you.

**Edit:** additional context, I am using kubernetes with the infinite loop container. I wonder if this `ctrl+c` problem (related to SIGINT) will interfere with kubernetes if I want to gracefully stop and exit the running pod. Note that although the `ctrl+c` is problematic, I was still able to use `docker stop` to stop the running containers.

Comment: @Deka Auliya docker kill is your best friend

Answer (score 12):

**“docker run” traps or ignores ctrl+c.**

If you don’t want to lose your shell you can trying stopping the container from another terminal on the same docker host.

Open a new shell and execute

```
$ docker ps # get the id of the running container
$ docker stop <container> # kill it (gracefully)
```

The container process will end and your original shell will be released.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to use trap, here's an example of my code:

```
done=0
trap 'done=1' TERM INT

while [ $done = 0 ]; do
  #doingstuff
  sleep $someinterval &
  wait
done
```

ctrl + c is a signal so you'll need a signal handler. Moreover sleep will need to be run in background so that your trap won't be held until sleep is completed.

[1] Trap: https://www.shellscript.sh/trap.html